# Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and multilabel-indicator targets when changing LSTM architecture

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook, lstm, sequential

I am building a LSTM algorithm to work as an IDS to make a multi-class classification.

As I am new to this I took a code from the internet :

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 21)))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(80, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])
monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, patience=5, 
                        verbose=1, mode='auto', restore_best_weights=True)
```

With this code accuracy decreases at about the 16th epch. But my main issue is not that one. If I use the following architecture the error shown at the title of this post is shown:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 21)))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])
monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, patience=5, 
                        verbose=1, mode='auto', restore_best_weights=True)
```

Why is that happening. Output should be the same for both models.

Thanks for your help.